# accessing files outside of web server with javascript (htaccess?)

Tags: php, javascript, macos, apache

I have a local server (Mac 10.8) that I am trying to serve files (video & images) off of an external harddrive (HD: /Volumes/ from Webserver: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default).

I am able to read all of the files on the external harddrive with PHP, but accessing them via the web browser (Javascript with JWPlayer) has turned out to be more difficult. I am guessing this can be done with an htaccess script, but my knowledge of htaccess is limited at best.

I tried an httpd.conf Alias (/media /Volumes/....) and restarted apache but only get a 404 error when navigating to the /media page.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Mac has a built in Alias feature that I was able to use and it worked. No idea why I couldn't get the aliasing to work in the httpd.conf, but I noticed the apache files were all pointing to older versions of the Mac OS: WebServer/ (From Snow Leopard when I upgraded).